# How to convert Samsung emoji code into a regular emoji in PHP?

Tags: php, emoji

I've searched everywhere for an answer to this but have yet to find;

I'm using a Wordpress shoutbox plugin, Schreikasten which was written some time ago. In the time since, Samsung and other Android devices have been using code such as

```
    &#55357;&#56832;
```

for a smiley face etc which is not being translated into an emoji with this plugin. What I'm trying to do is put together a function that will convert the Samsung code into an emoji. 
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: @Patrick Q, not really. I tried that solution with my surrogate pair and got nothing but a white square with a black border. Believe this may have more to do with a combination of that function and utf8/utf8mb4 encoding/decoding.